# Popup in windows phone app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

Is it possible to show some popup in any windows phone app based on user action, say I want to display one pop up when user tap once on the screen.

For example, in windows phone if you select any text with single Tap then it gives copy button as popup, similarly I wanted to display some popup when user tap it twice. And this should work in any app, like browser, email, message etc

Comment: Are you after [toast notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202967(v=vs.105).aspx)?

Comment: No, I am looking for something similar to how Copy icon come once you select some text in windows Phone.

Comment: You can bind to the events tap and hold, for double tap, you need to creator a timer in your code to specify when you say it is a tap or a double tap. There is the class popup, but very prone to memory leak, therefore you should create your own popup using canvas.zindex and simply force an element to the front of everything. Just my 2 cents :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like your application to show a "PopUp" on a certain user action in other applications. As far as I'm aware you are not allowed to have any interaction of this kind with other applications and there is no system API to define or add this kind of behavior (would be a security nightmare). You can send/share data with other applications, or have background tasks which can run your code in the background.

Comment: But looks like android does support, see this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.barisatamer.popupdictionary&hl=en, also how copy & paste works with all APP. I believe there must be something available which I can use to build an app.

Comment: @Nikhil  As Barptad said, it's a security precaution by microsoft. Only a few system features (implemented by MS) work in other apps, for example SpellChecker.  The security standards on android is different, so this "problem" does not apply there.

Answer (score 0):

> using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives; private void
>   btnShowPopUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>           {   //set the content to be hosted inside the popup.
>               PopupView.Child = new Popupview();//it is Popupview.xaml file
>               PopupView.IsOpen = true;
>
> ```
>         PopupView.VerticalOffset = 80;// distance of the popup from the top
>         PopupView.HorizontalOffset = 0;// distance of the popup from the left  }
> ```
>
> //in that Popupview.xaml file code